# How to disable an app

Tags: android

How can I disable another application by my app.
It can be by Disable or blocking it or disable it's notification listener.
For example I wanna disable a messenger in a period of time and this should has been managed by my app.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You have no rights to disable (or enable) components of another app. It can be done by owner user only.